# Data from local computer

Tags: javascript, d3.js, input, bubble-chart, loaddata

I would like to load data from a JSON file on my computer. I know that I can't read without HTTP server so I would like to creat an input field. My file is succeffuly read but when I send the data to function to create the Bubble Chart, nothing is created. If I load from local it works (I execute a HTTP server).
This is the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json;
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
    }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                        json = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
                        alert('json global var has been set to parsed json of this file here it is unevaled = \n' + JSON.stringify(json));
                        initData(JSON.stringify(json)); // Doesn't works
                        //initData("data.json"); // Works
                }
            })(f);
            reader.readAsText(f);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

</script>


 function initData(data){
          d3.json(data, function(error, root) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
// .....
```

This is an online example for Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/T8WFvj0qtMW5mFK6gOjO?p=preview

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers ! This is the good code, just send the JSON and dont use d3.json

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json;
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
    }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                        json = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
                        alert('json global var has been set to parsed json of this file here it is unevaled = \n' + JSON.stringify(json));
                        initData(json); // Doesn't works
                        //initData("data.json"); // Works
                }
            })(f);
            reader.readAsText(f);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

</script>

function initData(root){
        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
//....
```

Answer (score 1):

`d3.json` uses a file path for its first argument and passes the parsed json to its callback. Since you load and parse the json yourself, you don't need to use `d3.json`, and should just pass the json to the callback directly as `root`.

This should work: https://plnkr.co/edit/0H6t9m642cxCcukPwDFH?p=preview

If you also want to load via `d3.json` for something served from your server, you can do that using something like:

```
var loadFromUrl = function(url){
    d3.json(url, function(error, data){
        if(!error) {
           initData(data);
        }
    });
};
```